# Download different versions of sharepoint files without replacing them on the server

Tags: microsoft-edge, history, sharepoint

I have a bunch of xml files stored in a Sharepoint Document Library which are altered by a tool from time to time, so the files have a version history. Sometimes, I would like to know the exact difference of two versions of a file, but the Browser view of Sharepoint seems to lack a possibility to view or download different versions of that file. What I can do is to restore a specific version, which makes this version the currently active file which I definitely do not want, since this is a productive system.

I have also seen that a version history feature is available for files that can be opened in office applications, but for these xml files, I do not use any office application to view.

So the question is: how can I download different versions of a file so that I can compare them with Winmerge or another tool?

Answer (score 1):

In the Version History list for a file, click on the date link (not the dropdown) to open/download that version of the file directly:

[image]

These are direct vti history links that look this, where `[VID]` is the document version number x 512 (so version `5.0` becomes `2560` for example):

```
https://tentant.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/_vti_history/[VID]/LibraryName/FileName.txt
```

---

Restoring a document also creates a new version number, so you can always restore back to the "current" version if it got replaced by an older one.